# Convert numerical date into Datetime object

Tags: php, date, datetime

Just wondered what the best way to convert the date in the following format:
02072014 (2nd July 2014) into the \DateTime object? I've tried:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("jMY", $digits);
```

But that didn't seem to work. I'm using that date format because it's being entered on a phone keypad.

Cheers,

Ewan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function definition of `createFromFormat()`

```
public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

So you need to do as

```
$digits = '02072014';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY',$digits);
echo $date->format("j M Y");
```

Set the data in your desired format.

```
$date->format("j M Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format specifiers. From the [documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), `j` is used for day without leading zeroes, and `m` is for a month that is spelled out in English. Also, you should pass a `DateTimeZone` if you do not want `PHP` to guess.

```
<?php
$digits = "02072014";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("dmY", $digits, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the right format that the passed in string should be:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( "dmY", $digits );
```